# Row is added if no file is selected in a input type file

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I have a small question,

I have an Html form with a `<input type"file">` button...I have written some code for it so it saves the image name in a MySQL database. But if you select no image there is still a white line in the database.

This is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM ncr_input ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

$ncrnummer = $row[0];

for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['attachments']['name']); $i++)
{
    $filetmp = $_FILES["attachments"]["tmp_name"][$i];
    $filename = $_FILES["attachments"]["name"][$i];
    $filepath = "images/".$filename;

    move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);

    $querypictureupload = "INSERT INTO file_upload (ncrnummer,filename) VALUES ('$ncrnummer','$filename')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $querypictureupload);
}
```

After inserting the image in the database I want it in a FPDF:

```
$pdf->AddPage();

$query1 = "SELECT filename FROM `file_upload` WHERE ncrnummer = '$ncrnummer'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
if ($result1 -> num_rows >0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        $image = $row['filename'];
        $pdf->Image("images/".$image,NULL , NULL ,100,85, "");
        $pdf->Cell(190, 3, "", 0, 1);
    }
}
```

Here is the problem because if there is no file on that white line FPDF will give an error code...

Comment: So why not check to see if there is an image, and if there isn't don't draw it? `if ($row['filename']) { $pdf->Image("images/".$image,NULL , NULL ,100,85, ""); }`?

Comment: @FrankerZ, Thanks! that solved the problem. I'm still learning every day...

Comment: You should not check when generating the pdf, instead you should check for a valid file upload before adding a new entry to the database. The problem is meaningless records in your database, not the way you display it.

Comment: @jeroen, I put an if statement arround the $querypictureupload query.....so now it only add a new record if the move statement is executed